# Debugging App Engine usage CPU requirements and amounts

Tags: php, node.js, google-app-engine, child-process

I was load testing app engine, so I set it to use one instance of the default type (which is `B1`). It has 256 MB or RAM and 600 MHz 1 CPU processing (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard).

I have a nodejs script that runs a php script that does 1 MYSQL lookup query on a timer. Currently this timer checks four times a second. I wanted to test how many users this could support, so I divided the timer by different amounts to simulate how many operations different amounts of users would use.

To my dismay, I found that with 5 simulated users, the instance runs at about 80% CPU. That means the app is running the loop 40 times per second, which seems like it would be like having 40 http requests per second. I've read that one can support 7200 requests per second with an `F1` server, which has the same specs as a `B1` server. Is this high CPU usage expected and/or is there something I can do to debug this and possibly make it more efficient?

Here's more information about the flow of the program:

1. User connects with socket.io and joins a room
2. Server runs a script on a timer running 4 times a second.
3. The script uses `child_process` to run a php script that performs a MySQL query to a Cloud SQL server to determine if there have been any updates worth gathering from the MySQL database. (Right now I'm only testing that there haven't been any updates, so running any extra queries is skipped in these tests.)
4. The php script returns JSON data to the server, and the server sees that there's nothing more to be done.

   Normally the script would only run once per room type (regardless of number of users), but to test how much processing the server can handle, I divided the timer duration by different amounts and found that at 5x the frequency, the server runs at 80% CPU. What this is technically suggesting is that if there are constantly 4 new messages, the CPU usage is predicted to be about 80%. This seems high to me.

So, I'm wondering now if the `child_process` running a php script is using very high amounts of CPU, as it seems to be the only thing that could possibly be using that much. Insight or suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

> I've read that one can support 7200 requests per second with an F1 server, which has the same specs as a B1 server. Is this high CPU usage expected and/or is there something I can do to debug this and possibly make it more efficient?

B1 are not exactly the same as F1 instances. While it is true that B1 and F1 share the same specs, as you stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard) for B1 instances the only supported scaling types are manual and basic.

In other words, B1 instances are scaled using manual and basic scaling, which can cause issues if you do not set the expectations of your applications right in your app.yaml.

If you define a low number of instances and you have traffic spikes, you will be left alone with the instances already spawned, causing them to receive all the traffic, effectively spiking up CPU and memory usage too.

My recommendation is to go with instance class that supports automatic scaling. Automatic scaling is not only good because you don't need to set exact expectations of what your traffic may look like, but you can define a [minimum number of instance](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#automatic_scaling_min_instances) and a [maximum number of instances](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#automatic_scaling_max_instances), and Google App Engine will take care of up scaling or down scaling the instances in regards with your traffic.

That effectively as a consequence helps reduce load across all your instance class already spawned, which means lower CPU and memory usage and overall better performance than compare with manual or basic scaling.

Also, [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-requests-are-handled) you will find documentation regarding how request are handled in Google App Engine standard as well as some tips and best practices to take advantage of in order to improve performance and stability.

Finally, if you decide to go through with instance class that support automatic scaling, enabling warmup request can help not only reduce latency but the overall performance of your code by loading a fresh copy of your application before a new instance class is created. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/configuring-warmup-requests) you will find more information about warmup requests.

I hope it helps.

Comment: With automatic scaling, if an F1 instance only supports 5 users, then the highest, (F4_1G) will likely only support 4 times that (20 users), and the quota to max instances is set to 8, which will mean I would only be able to support about 160 users completely maxed out, so I don't think that would solve it. I didn't think I was using much processing power in the script, but apparently I am. It goes from start, to running a php script with a database connection and a single query, to handling the response in node.js with a few lines of code, for one cycle, which is done 4 times per user-second

Comment: If your setup is really consuming that much, in case you use automatic scaling, once the CPU usage or the traffic is high enough, when using automatic scaling, Google App Engine will spawn another instance that will support more users for your workflow, and this can be extended as long as your maximum number of instances is concerned. What I meant by using automatic scaling it's that it not only help CPU usage by distributing the users between different spawned instances classes, but also gives you the possibility to scale without any issues as long as your application needs it.